# How to obtain a private key for "Developer ID Application" or "Developer ID Installer" certificates?

Tags: xcode, macos, electron, certificate, notarize

I'd like to understand how to obtain a private key for **Developer ID Application** or **Developer ID Installer** certificates?

[image]

1. *Developer ID* certificates may be created only by **Account Holder** https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ - **done**
2. I have `Developer ID Application` certificate.
3. But there is missing private key.

Where may I find the appropriate private key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To share *Developer ID* certificates the person who is **Account Holder** should:

1. Crete *Developer ID* certificate on developer account https://developer.apple.com/
2. Import it to keychain
3. Export certificate together with private key as *p12* file
4. Share to developer *p12* file with password

Answer (score 2):

Ask the person who created this certificate to export the certificate and send it to you. Or any other existing developer who is already using this certificate.

You can not download private keys from the apple developer portal.

Comment: Yep, the person who created certificate must import `Developer ID *` certificate to the original keychain and export certificate + private key as .p12 bundle.

It is not obvious when certificate created through web (not Xcode).